# Question related to the symmetric algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have the following question. Let us suppose that $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Is there any isomorphism from $\text{S}^{i}(\text{S}^{j}V)$ to $\text{S}^{i\cdot j}(V)$?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is not: in general, $\dim(S^i(V)) = \binom{\dim V + i - 1}{i}.$ Suppose that $\dim V = i = j = 2.$ Then we have $\dim S^2(V) = \binom{2 + 2 - 1}{2} = 3,$ and $\dim(S^2(S^2(V))) = \binom{\dim S^2(V) + 2 - 1}{2} = \binom{4}{2} = 6.$ On the other hand, $\dim(S^4(V)) = \binom{2 + 4 - 1}{4} = \binom{5}{4} = 5.$

Comment: There is, however, a nontrivial $GL(V)$-equivariant surjection from the former to the latter.